# Is Einstein Send Time Optimization reliable?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-analytics, einstein, einstein-analytics-dashboards

[image]

In the above snapshot of Einstein send time optimization dashboard, **can we know which are these 5 email addresses** that Einstein has predicted and can assign personalized send time?

I am monitoring this dashboard for the past 3 weeks now and I don't see the statistics changing.

I created a journey and ran it for 5 contacts. Before the email, I put Einstein STO activity. All the emails were sent at the same time. And these were the email addresses that are used very frequently for testing purpose(from the past 5-6 months) and hence, there should be a lot of open, clicks information that is available for these email addresses. Hence, I found it a bit illogical that why the email was sent to all the email addresses at the exact same time.

**Has anybody created a journey and witnessed different send times for different contacts?**

Comment: SO currently there is not a way to visualize the emails that have score and sends happen at the best hour. What does the dashboard say about best send time. Since you said these are test address do they have enough different data to have different send times base don hour, or is the engagement data all similar